# Quickest most efficient way to run a loop to find and verify over 1 million usernames off a different website?

Tags: php, curl

Using PHP the current script does work but obviously it's going to take an extremely long time since there are over 1 million usernames to verify.

This checks against the external websites API and returns `<span class="user">{userID}</span>` if it's a valid username and returns `<span class="user">0</span>` if it's not.

```
    $query = $db->query('SELECT id, username FROM users_to_verify'); // Over 1 million.
    foreach($query as $row) {
    $userID = $row['id'];
    $userName = $row['username'];
    if(!preg_match("/<span class=\"user\">0<\/span>/", file_get_contents("http://website.net/api.php?userName=".$userName)))
            $db->query('UPDATE users_to_verify SET verified = 1 WHERE id = $userID');
        }
    }
```

Is this the quickest way to do this? I've also dabbled with cURL but both file_get_contents and cURL seem to have the same performance, I also know that some of it will be dependent on the external websites response time, but I want to make sure that my side is using the quickest and best approach possible.

Comment: The bottleneck is going to be the response time of the remote site. Differences between curl or alternatives will be negligible. Be sure the remote site doesn't have rate limits, they may throttle or even block you.

Comment: Look into multi_curl, might save you some time

Comment: 1,000,000 iterations of `preg_match()` are definitely going to slow you down. You should do `if(file_get_contents("http://website.net/api.php?userName=".$userName) !=== '<span class="user">0</span>')` instead

Comment: do you have the rights to nail that site a million times? Don't start crying if they block you for abuse.

Comment: Yes, I have the rights.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `file_get_contentes` and `cUrl` performance. But you can boost your speed by run all your query in one command :

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT id, username FROM users_to_verify'); // Over 1 million.
$update_query = [];
foreach($query as $row) {
$userID = $row['id'];
$userName = $row['username'];
if(!preg_match("/<span class=\"user\">0<\/span>/", file_get_contents("http://website.net/api.php?userName=".$userName)))
        $update_query[] = 'UPDATE users_to_verify SET verified = 1 WHERE id = $userID';
    }
}
$db->query(implode(';',$update_query));
```

in this case you don't have to connect and run query in every step of loop.

*edit*:

It would be even better to only collect the verified userIds and then use `WHERE id IN(implode(',', $userIds))`. So MySQL only has to handle a single query.

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT id, username FROM users_to_verify'); // Over 1 million.
$userIDs = [];
foreach($query as $row) {
$userID = $row['id'];
$userName = $row['username'];
if(!preg_match("/<span class=\"user\">0<\/span>/", file_get_contents("http://website.net/api.php?userName=".$userName)))
        $userIDs[] = $userID;
    }
}
$db->query('UPDATE users_to_verify SET verified = 1 WHERE id IN('.implode(',', $userIDs).')');
```

Comment: that'll do essentially nothing. the bottleneck is file_get_contents() - waiting for the remote website is pretty much ALWAYS going to be MUCH slower than the local db call. and not all dbs let you run multiple queries in a single query() call anyways, so this won't work in most cases (mysql especially).

Comment: Of course the db is not the bottleneck, still if there is room for improvement in other places it should be pointed out. IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this not using a loop while the site is open, try doing it in the background, let PHP do the work in the background like a Cron Job.

Check this out:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428